# How to determine age on certain date in SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, openquery

I have the "Date Of Birth" in `DD-MMM-YY` format and "As on Date" `DD-MM-YYYY` format in a SQL Server query. I have to determine the AGE of person from above data on "As on Date". I created some logic as below to determine the age. It works fine when i run it on the oracle server.

```
select 
    case 
       when trunc(months_between(TRUNC(TO_DATE('08-05-2019', 'dd-mm-yy')), to_date(CM.MMRBRY, 'DD-mm-YY')) / 12) > 0 
          then trunc(months_between(TRUNC(TO_DATE('08-05-2019', 'dd-mm-yy')), to_date(CM.MMRBRY, 'DD-mm-YY')) / 12)
          else (99 + trunc(months_between(TRUNC(TO_DATE('08-05-2019', 'dd-mm-yy')), to_date(CM.MMRBRY, 'DD-mm-YY')) / 12)) 
     end as AGE
 from 
     LIIL_SA.COMPRLMMR CM
```

But I need to call this query from SQL Server using Open Query. When I execute this from open query on SQL Server using below code, then I am getting an error.

```
set @Query = @Query + ' case when trunc(months_between(TRUNC(TO_DATE(''''' + @AsOnDate + ''''',''''dd-mm-yy'''')),to_date(CM.MMRBRY,''''DD-mm-YY''''))/12)>0 then     '
set @Query = @Query + '   trunc(months_between(TRUNC(TO_DATE(''''' + @AsOnDate + ''''',''''dd-mm-yy'''')),to_date(CM.MMRBRY,''''DD-mm-YY''''))/12) '
set @Query = @Query + '    else (99+trunc(months_between(TRUNC(TO_DATE(''''' + @AsOnDate + ''''',''''dd-mm-yy'''')),to_date(CM.MMRBRY,''''DD-mm-YY''''))/12)) end as AGE '
```

Error is :

> OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "ASSURANCE" returned message "ORA-01861: literal does not match format string".
>   OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "ASSURANCE" returned message "ORA-01861: literal does not match format string".

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: This sounds like you have a date string that does not match the format specifier.

Comment: can you please tell me some other way to calculate the age in sql query. I have already specified the formats. The CM.MMRBRY can be null for few rows

Comment: is this `t-sql` or `oracle`?

Comment: `trunc()` is not really needed if you use `to_date()` without a time part. What data type is `CM.MMRBRY`? If that is a DATE, then do **not** call  `to_date()` on it. You should then use `months_between(TO_DATE('08-05-2019', 'dd-mm-yy'), CM.MMRBRY)`  - using `trunc()`  on a value returned by to_date() that doesn't specify a time is useless.